# Unable to proceed with FirebaseFirestore

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
>   initialized in this process com.example.callsmslogs. Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Comment: If you search for previous [questions with that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bandroid%5D+Default+FirebaseApp+is+not+initialized+in+this+process+), you'll find a lot of developers who have dealt with it before.

Comment: Did you put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of your app level `build.gradle` file?